# Users can't complete sign up because they get Redirected

Tags: php, redirect

Users can't complete sign up because they get Redirected. I still want to keep the Redirection because I only want people to see the site after they join.

Is there any way I can block a page from getting Redirected I am using php I am using mod from http://www.janrain.com/

I already have a log in/ log out / Register/ that work without getting Redirected I am trying to make so they can just signup with there Facebook etc... with http://www.janrain.com/

this is the code i am using that work but can't seem to get it to work with janrain

```
if ((int)$_COOKIE['memberID'] == 0) {
if (
    $_page['header'] != 'Join' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'About Us' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'Privacy Policy' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'Terms of use' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'FAQ' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'Invite a friend' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'Contact us' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'Help' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'Advice' &&
    $_page['header'] != 'Forgot password?'
    ) {
    header('Location: ' . BX_DOL_URL_ROOT . 'splash.php');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe $_page['header'] not in those so it will go to splash I will give you a better way to organize your work and help you in the future

```
    $pages = array("Join", "About Us", "Privacy Policy", "Terms of use","FAQ","Invite a friend","Contact us","Help","Advice","Forgot password?");
    if ((int)$_COOKIE['memberID'] == 0):
         if (!in_array($_page['header'],$pages):
            header('Location: ' . BX_DOL_URL_ROOT . 'splash.php');
         endif; 
    endif;
```

after finishing the above try to kill the page with $_page['header'] for debugging where we are

```
die($_page['header']); //just for debug
```

Comment: I am sorry @ UserB what do you mean by "now before all of that try to write this" die($_page['header']); //just for debug  what do you mean

Comment: Sorry if its not clear but i meant to put it before the first code to know what is the value of $_page['header']; then you can determine what is going on

Comment: I think its rendered as html file make sure that the code in <?php  //code ?> tags

Comment: And I amde this for you because when you need to add another statement you can easily add it to the array instead of adding a long if statement

Comment: Ok the code that I use work. I just can seem to get the login script from janrain to work without getting Redirected back to the splash.php and thanks for your help means a lot just wish i can get this to work

Comment: In order to determine what is going on we need to know what is the value of $_page['header']; so please put it in die($_pages); at the start of the login page 
the code here is the same as yours but in good style

Comment: with out added the Redirected they can login or join using  janrain i add the header from member-rpx.php that it get Redirected to          
 $_page['header'] = 'Required Fields';

Comment: and this value is not in the array or the if statment so it will go to splash

Comment: ok i added did this to member-rpx.php $_page['name_index'] = 13; 
 die($_pages);
 $_page['header'] = 'Required Fields';
 $_ni = $_page['name_index'];
 
 $oLiveJoinPageView = new LJoinPageView();
 $_page_cont[$_ni]['page_main_code'] = $oLiveJoinPageView->getCode();
 
 PageCode();

Comment: and $_page['header'] != 'Required Fields' && to the first code the page stop Redirected but the  member-rpx.php is blank